# how to write finding output to same file using awk command

Tags: bash, shell, awk

```
awk '/^nameserver/ && !modif { printf("nameserver 127.0.0.1\n"); modif=1 } {print}' testfile.txt
```

It is displaying output but I want to write the output to same file. In my example `testfile.txt`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [awk save modifications inplace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/awk-save-modifications-inplace)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Not possible per se. You need a second temporary file because you can't read and overwrite the same file.  Something like:

```
awk '(PROGRAM)' testfile.txt > testfile.tmp && mv testfile.tmp testfile.txt
```

The `mktemp` program is useful for generating unique temporary file names.

There are some hacks for avoiding a temporary file, but they rely mostly on caching and read buffers and quickly get unstable for larger files.

Comment: Is there a temporary file syntax that results in the file being deleted afterwards?  I saw a ddwrt script that was something like tempfile._$$ and it never removed the file.

Comment: You may want to use `mv -f testfile.tmp testfile.txt` to overwrite the file

Answer (score 22):

Since GNU Awk 4.1.0, there is the "inplace" extension, so you can do:

```
$ gawk -i inplace '{ gsub(/foo/, "bar") }; { print }' file1 file2 file3
```

To keep a backup copy of original files, try this:

```
$ gawk -i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak '{ gsub(/foo/, "bar") }
> { print }' file1 file2 file3
```

This can be used to simulate the GNU `sed -i` feature.

See: [Enabling In-Place File Editing](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html)

Answer (score 10):

Despite the fact that using a temp file is correct, I don't like it because :

- you have to be sure not to erase another temp file (yes you can use mktemp - it's a pretty usefull tool)
- you have to take care of deleting it (or moving it like thiton said) INCLUDING when your script crash or stop before the end (so deleting temp files at the end of the script is not that wise)
- it generate IO on disk (ok not that much but we can make it lighter)

So my method to avoid temp file is simple:

```
my_output="$(awk '(PROGRAM)' source_file)"
echo "$my_output" > source_file
```

Note the use of double quotes either when grabbing the output from the awk command AND when using echo (if you don't, you won't have newlines).

Answer (score 8):

Had to make an account when seeing 'awk' and 'not possible' in one sentence. Here is an awk-only solution without creating a temporary file:

```
awk '{a[b++]=$0} END {for(c=1;c<=b;c++)print a[c]>ARGV[1]}' file
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer here, thought it's greatly underestimated.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `sponge` from [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/).

For example

```
awk '!a[$0]++' file|sponge file
```

removes duplicate lines and

```
 awk '{$2=10*$2}1' file|sponge file
```

multiplies the second column by 10.

Answer (score 1):

Try to include statement in your awk file so that you can find the output in a new file. Here total is a calculated value.

```
print $total, total >> "new_file"
```

Answer (score 0):

This inline writing worked for me. Redirect the output from print back to the original file.

```sh
echo "1" > test.txt
awk '{$1++; print> "test.txt"}' test.txt
cat test.txt
#$> 2
```