# How do I remove a particular pattern with a number sequence sed

Tags: regex, sed

I'm very new to sed bash command, so trying to learn.

I'm currently faced with a few thousand markdown files i need to clean up and I'm trying to create a command that deletes part of the following

```
# null 864: Headline
body text
```

I need anything that come before the headline deleted which is '# null 864: '
it's allways: '# null ' then some digits ': '
I'm using gnu-sed because I'm using mac

The best I've come up with sofar is

```
gsed -i '/#\snull\s([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]):\s/d' *.md
```

The above does not seem to work?

however if I do

```
gsed -i '/#\snull/d' *.md
```

it does what I want, however it does some unintended stuff in the body test.

How do I control so only the headline and the body text remains?

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you want to print values before headline and don't want to print any other lines, then try following.

```
sed -E -n 's/^(#\s+null\s+[0-9]+:\s+)Headline/\1/p' Input_file
```

In case you want to print value before Headline and if match is not found want to print that complete line then try following:

```
sed -E 's/^(#\s+null\s+[0-9]+:\s+)Headline/\1/' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple using `-E` option of `sed` to enable ERE(extended regular expression), then using `s` option of `sed` to perform substitution here. matching # followed by space(s) null followed by space(s) digits colon and space(s) and keeping it in 1st capturing group, while substitution, substituting it with 1st capturing group.

***NOTE:*** Above commands will print values on terminal, in case you want to save them inplace then use `-i` option once you are satisfied with above code's output.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you have files like this:

```
This should get deleted
This should too.
# null 864: Headline
body text
this should get kept
```

You want to keep the headline, and everything after, right?  You can do this in awk:

```
awk '/# null [0-9]+:/,eof {print}' foo.md
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use awk, and replace the `# null 864:`  part with an empty string using sub.

See [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019617/how-to-write-finding-output-to-same-file-using-awk-command) to either create a new file, or to overwrite the same file.

The `}1` prints the whole line as 1 evaluates to true.

```
awk '{sub(/^# null [0-9]+:[[:blank:]]+/,"")}1' file
```

The pattern matches

- `^# null`  Match literally from the start of the string
- `[0-9]+:[[:blank:]]+` match 1+ digits, then `:` and 1+ spaces

Output

```
Headline
body text
```

Answer (score 0):

On a mac `ed` should be installed by default so.

The content of `script.ed`

```
g/^# null [[:digit:]]\{1,\}: Headline$/s/^.\{1,\}: //
,p
Q
```

---

```
for file in *.md; do ed -s "$file" < ./script.ed; done
```

If the output is ok, remove the `,p` and change the `Q` to `w` so it can edit the file *in-place*

```
g/^# null [[:digit:]]\{1,\}: Headline$/s/^.\{1,\}: //
w
```

Run the loop again.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a range in `sed` same as Andy Lester's `awk` solution.
Borrowing his infile,

```
$: cat tst.md
This should get deleted
This should too.
# null 864: Headline
body text
this should get kept

$: sed -Ein '/^# null [0-9]+:/,${p;d};d;' tst.md
$: cat tst.md
# null 864: Headline
body text
this should get kept
```